# Formula Parse Error in IF nesting function google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested

This is the Formula:

=IF(E2<30001, E2*0.05, IF(E2<60001, 30000*0.05+(E2-30000)*0.1, 30000*0.05+30000*0.1+(E2-60000)*0.2))

It keeps bringing up parse errors and I cannot figure out why :( Can you help?

I have try checking for Syntax errors, and splitting the Formula up, but that wasn´t successful. I replaced the "," with ";" but then i receicve an #N/A error: Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use semicolons instead of commas:

```
=IF(E2<30001; E2*0,05; IF(E2<60001; 30000*0,05+(E2-30000)*0,1; 30000*0,05+30000*0,1+(E2-60000)*0,2))
```

Comment: Yes i tried that while checking the syntax but then i receicve an #N/A error: Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments.

Comment: can you share a sample sheet?

Comment: This solved my problem of getting a parse error with a formula as simple as `=AND(D2,E2)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(E2<30001, E20.05, IF(E2<60001, 300000.05+(E2-30000)0.1, 300000.05+30000*0.1+(E2-60000)*0.2))
```

I can see a few errors in your formula, The Second argument "E20.05" please check that once if you want it to be E2*0.05 or something like that, you're not using the multiplication symbol.

The second argument inside the nested IF is "300000.05+(E2-30000)0.1"
In this as well you are missing a multiplication sign right after the bracket. based on my understanding it should be written as 300000.05+(E2-30000)*0.1

Additionally please check your formula once again, it is unclear to me whether you have used dot (.) for multiplication instead of asterisk (*), in google sheets  a dot will just mean decimal point. In case you have used dot as a decimal point then as per me the corrected formula will be

```
=IF(E2<30001, E2*0.05, IF(E2<60001, 300000.05+(E2-30000)*0.1, 300000.05+30000*0.1+(E2-60000)*0.2))
```